# How to insert text in Beamer Title Page just below title

Tags: beamer, titles

[image: How to insert text in Beamer Title Page just below title]

How to insert text in Beamer Title Page just below title

Comment: You may need to redefine/patch the `title page` beamer template. In the default inner theme it's defined by [these lines](https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/blob/acd26cf1b6187d985de2bf401b86ed83aa8d689e/base/themes/inner/beamerinnerthemedefault.sty#L38-L67). I'm willing to provide more help if you can show the themes used in your beamer document, usually as an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).